# Google Calendar API missing calendar summary

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to add calendars to Google through a Python script.

Relevant code:

```
with open("primo1.json") as f:
    cal = json.loads(f.read())
calId = cal[0]["title"]
print(calId)

try:
    resCalendar = service.calendars().get(calendarId=calId).execute()
except:
    newCal = {}
    newCal["timeZone"] = "Europe/Rome"
    newCal["summary"] = str(calId.split(" ", 1)[0])
    newCal["kind"] = "calendar#calendar"
    newCal["id"] = str(calId.replace(" ", ""))
    newCal["etag"] = str(hashlib.md5(bencode.bencode(newCal)).hexdigest())
    #print(newCal["etag"])

    newCal = json.dumps(newCal)
    res = service.calendars().insert(body=newCal).execute()
#print(resCalendar)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 60, in main
    res = service.calendars().insert(body=newCal).execute()
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?alt=json returned "Missing summary.". Details: "Missing summary.">
```

The summary I add to newCal dict is just a string (in this case "ARCHITETTURA")

Whole code just in case you need it: https://pastebin.com/vQNwjJ0x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are providing a JSON formatted string to the request body, returned by [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and you should be providing a dictionary (see [insert(body=None)](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.calendars.html#insert)). Because of this, the property `summary` cannot be found in the request body, and since this property is required (see [request body](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert#request-body)), you are getting the error `Missing summary`. Therefore, you should remove the line `newCal = json.dumps(newCal)`.
- `kind`, `id` and `etag` are not writable properties (see [Calendar resource representation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource-representations)); they are provided by Google and the values you set will be ignored. Therefore, there's no point in setting these fields in your dictionary.

#### Code snippet:

```
newCal = {
  "summary": "Your summary",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Rome"
}
res = service.calendars().insert(body=newCal).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

This method takes a JSON string as its parameter.  So if you want to use a dictionary you would need to covert your dictionary to a json string for the request body.

Also you dont need to set id, kind or etag Google creates those values as they are not writeable by you in the request. [calendars resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource)

The documentation gives an example of how to make the call [Calendar.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert#python)

```
calendar = {
    'summary': 'calendarSummary',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}

created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. As a side note, it does NOT work if i try to do the same by building a dictionary and dumping it as a json. I'll be leaving the question open for a bit in case someone could explain that behaviour.

Comment: Im glad i was able to help